# Size of font in vmin as percent of container

Tags: css

working on a class project, and something has our whole class, including our teacher, stumped. We're making a calculator out of html, css and javascript. The problem involves CSS. We have set the calculator  to height: 50vmin and width: 50vmin.

We then set font-size to 5vmin, expecting it to be 10% of the container height. Instead, the font size is coming out to be around 11-12% or more of the height. For example, on my screen, the container is 323.5 px and the font-size is 37.981px. This does not include the padding or margin: it is the font-size itself. Does anyone know why the font is not coming out 10%? With 5 rows of buttons, plus margins and padding, it makes quite a difference.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a full jsfiddle code example with html and css. From what I can tell setting the font-size to vmin should work

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dtarvin/d7uc7k67/5/

Comment: jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dtarvin/d7uc7k67/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
font-size: 10vh;
```

1vh = 1% of viewport height

Comment: Thanks, there's a problem with that. We are seeking to be 10% of the container height, not the viewport height. The container is set to vmin, so it will always be 1/2 of either the height or the width of the viewport. We need to use a unit for the font that is responsive, hence the vmin.